# Using Tempfile to create a zip file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, temporary-files

I want to create a temporary .zip in rails. For creating zip file I am using `rubyzip` gem.

Currently I am doing this:

```
zfname = Tempfile.new(['somename','.zip'], Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/')
Zip::ZipFile.open(zfname.path, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  zipfile.add(file, basepath + file)
end
```

This generates following error:

```
Zip::ZipError: Zip end of central directory signature not found
```

Is it possible to use `Tempfile` for zip? If yes, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my rails app when I needed to send zip files to user, I just stored them in a buffer and used 'send data' method in controller.
I was trying to use 'Tempfile' initially but it had an added task of removing zip files after sending it to user which is a pain.
Is this something you are looking for?

```
    Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |stream|
      file_paths.each_with_index do |file_path, index|
        # rename the pdf
        stream.put_next_entry("#{name}-#{index + 1}.pdf")
        # add pdf to zip
        stream.write IO.read(file_path)
      end  
    end
```

Comment: Though you are still not using `TempFile`, but this is a much better solution to my problem. Thanks +1

Comment: good luck...I was deleting the Tempfile initially in delayed_job...oh the horror. That's when I decided to open up the gem and do everything in the buffer.

Comment: @AdityaShedge would this be practical on Heroku, where dynos have very limitted memory?

Comment: @Mohamad Depends on how big your zip file can get. In my case I knew that it would not go beyond a few Mb's...which I can live with since writing a file on disk and cleaning it later was much more hassle. If ur file size goes above 1/4 the memory size the it could be a problem.

Comment: @AdityaShedge thanks. Just to be specific, this builds the file in RAM, and then sends it to the user. It does not stream the file on the fly, right? As it it has to finish building the file first before it sends it as a response.

Comment: @Mohamad Yes builds the complete file first.

Comment: In the case your variable storing the buffer is named `buffer`, don't forget to invoke `buffer.string` in the `send_data` call.

Answer (score 8):

So it doesn't actually look like you need or want a Tempfile.  You really want a random path in the Rails.root/tmp directory.  Try something like this:

```
zfpath = Rails.root.join('tmp', "somename-#{SecureRandom.hex(8)}.zip"
Zip::ZipFile.open(zfpath, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  zipfile.add(file, basepath + file)
end
```

Update:

While it's far more complex, you can find a discussion of how to do this with a Tempfile here - http://thinkingeek.com/2013/11/15/create-temporary-zip-file-send-response-rails/ .

Comment: I am able to accomplish what you suggest. However this is not my aim. I want to use a tempfile as this is a temporary action in my code. I will delete the file after one more step. Though it can be done your suggested way too, but it i am specifically looking for tempfile for that purpose. Thanks