# How to gzip html documents before uploading to S3 using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a rails model with an attachment (html document).

When creating a new attachment and uploading to s3 using fog, I would like to compress the document with gzip before uploading to s3, to save space and upload time. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27580605/2144445?

Comment: it's not that I don't know how to gzip a string (`gzip = ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress('compress me!')`), it's more how I can do this for an upload with carrier wave